# Does @Html.Editfor use data bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to know if @Html.Editfor use databind. In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx

They say that it use a for each method, but one of my colleague makes me doubt by saying that this is databind.

Answer (score 0):

They have mentioned on their page

> Returns an HTML input element for each property in the object that is
>   represented by the .....

Here they are saying that @Html.EditFor is available for each property of the model. Its not same as its using foreach. This is indeed data binding.